# Supply arduino through Vin pin with a battery

Tags: arduino-mega, battery

1. is it dangerous for arduino the below circuit because GND pin is common with -12V battery pole?
2. is it dangerous for lots of 5v circuit to be grounded on -12v battery pole?
3. in case i don't connect GND arduino pin with -12v , does arduino works?
4. in case that 1,2 question is dangerous for arduino,does it safe if a connect a diode at P1 mark?

[image]

Comment: You seem to be confusing ground and negative voltages an awful lot...

Comment: if a want to supply arduino with a battery which should be the connections?

Comment: there is no `-12v` in a battery, it is `GND`. So all `-5v` and `-12v` you have there are `GND`. Unless it is an ACTUAL negative voltage derived from the same power source, then it is irrelevant

Comment: Change your diagram's three '-5v' and one '-12v' to GND and the "+voltage" to be  "+5V".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voltages, being a *potential difference* are always measured relative to another voltage.  Normally that reference voltage is referred to as *ground*, though may not always be.

The + and - on the battery refers to the *polarity of the battery* not the *polarity of the voltage*.

For instance, *relative to the - terminal* the positive terminal is 12 volts higher, or +12V.  *Relative to the + terminal* the negative terminal is 12V lower, so -12V.

When one of your battery terminals is connected to a point in your circuit nominated as ground (the - terminal of your battery in this case) then your battery voltage at the + terminal is measured relative to ground, which we say is 0V.  So the + terminal is 12V higher than the - terminal, and the - terminal is 0V, so therefore the + terminal must be 12V *with respect to ground*.  The - terminal, since it is connected to ground is at the same voltage as ground, so it is 0V *with respect to ground*.

If you were to connect the + terminal of a battery to ground instead, then the - terminal would be 12V *lower* than ground, so would be -12V *with respect to ground*.  The + terminal would be 0V *with respect to ground*.